# Does $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \left (e^{-x}+2x\cos 3x \right)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that the limit doesn't exist if the $2x$ wasn't there since $e^-x$ is just $\dfrac{1}{e^x}$ which tends to $0$ as $x$ approaches $\infty,$ and $\cos 3x$ is just an oscillating function so it doesn't converge. But if the $2x$ is there would the limit just be infinity?

Answer (score 2):

It still doesn’t exist, because $\cos 3x$ also equals $0$ at regular periods of time, so the entire thing equals $0$ at that point. The limit would oscillate vigorously.

Answer (score 2):

No, the limit doesn't exist. For instance$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-2\pi n}+4\pi n\cos(6\pi n)=\infty,$$whereas$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-(2\pi n+\pi/3)}+\left(4\pi n+2\frac\pi3\right)\cos(6\pi n+\pi)=-\infty.$$